# How to get the main CultureInfo for a country in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a asp.net mvc application where i need to localize the currency format.
so i decided to let the user choose the country from where i can use the RegionInfo to find the currency symbol and run the query on CultureInfo and set the first result as the culture for the user.
 Here is my code:

```
        public string GetPrimaryUICulture(string CountryCd) {
        CultureInfo Info;
        var _CultureInfox = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo(CountryCd);
        var _CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith(CountryCd)).ToList();
        if (_CultureInfo.Count == 0)
        {
            Info = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        }
        else
        {

            Info = _CultureInfo.Where(p => p.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol == _CultureInfox.CurrencySymbol).FirstOrDefault();
           // Info = _CultureInfo.Where(p => p.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals("en")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Info == null)
            {
                Info = _CultureInfo.Where(p => p.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals("en")).FirstOrDefault();
                if (Info == null)
                {
                    Info = _CultureInfo.FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }
        return Info.Name;
    }
```

Now the problem is , if i set the CountryCd as "IN", the result i get from the above function is as-IN, for which i dont have the angularjs i18n file; what i have is hi-IN.

Another solution is to retrive the CultureInfo, that matches as en-{{CountryName}}, but there is a currency problem. For India, this works, but for Malaysia(en-MY), it gives $ instead of RM.

if things come to worse i have to hard code as : if IN then hi-IN, if MY, then ms-MY. if CH, then ZH-CN etc...which i really dont wanna do.

I hope you understand the problem i'm facing, sorry about my bad english, if you need further clarifications, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

While it's web application u can simply analyze  HTTP language/locale headers and not try to guess it from custom field.

Most browsers in setup set valid locale at first place.

Detailed here:

http://matthewwittering.com/blog/internationalization-localization/http-headers.html

Comment: you are right, but, in my case, my primary browser language is set to en-MY and the currency format is $ instead of RM, what i expect is the main locale, ms-MY.

Comment: but i think it's more "ecological" for web to bind locale to standart featrures for most people and provide custom manual choise for advanced. Guessing is not good idea i think.